# Angular with CSS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

really stupid question but its to weird. 
I am trying to separate between 2 div`s, one to the left and one to the right.
I was trying to use CSS property "float" but nothing happens.

[image]

EDIT:
html

```
 <h4>Profile</h4>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="text-form">Full Name</div>
                    <div class="inner">
                        <input type="text" class="account-box" ng-model="name">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="text-form">Company Name</div>
                    <div class="inner">
                        <input type="text" class="account-box" ng-model="companyName">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: static;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: left;
}

.inner {
  display:inline-block;
  position:static;
  top:2px;
  padding-right:10px;
  clear: both;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Share your CSS as well

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: Your screenshot and HTML show completely different things. Provide a real [mcve]

Comment: edit the post. sorry

Comment: @OrPerets — The CSS is still missing. Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope to be able to help you

```
<div class="input-group" style="width: 300px;display: flex;justify-content: space-between;">
    <div class="text-form">Full Name</div>
    <div class="inner">
        <input type="text" class="account-box" ng-model="name">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: amazing. thanks! can you explain me why? for next time

Comment: Display: flex means flexible layout, justify-content define Alignment of child elements

Answer (score 9):

```
<div class="container">
    <h4>Password Change</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="text-form" id="left">Password <span style="color:red;">*</span> 
            <input type="password" placeholder="required" class="account-box" required="" ng-model="password">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a div of mine, where one sits to the left and one to the right, via float, and margins to fit them in. And dont forget the clear:both at the end so that no problems arise with elements coming afterwards. Hope this helps :)

```
<div style="border-style:none">
    <table id="table_user" style="border-style:ridge;width: 22%;float: left; margin-top:20px; margin-left:10px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style= 'width:10%'>Benutzer</th>
                <th style= 'width:10%'>Check </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>  
<div style="border-style:none">
    <table id="table_benutzergruppe" style="border-style:ridge;width: 25%;float: left;margin-left: 25px; margin-top:20px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style= 'width:10%'>Benutzergruppe</th>
                <th style= 'width:10%'>Check </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```